# How to open email or any other mail app with intent in android compose

Tags: android, android-intent, android-jetpack-compose

How can I open email app in another screen "tab"?

When I send a reset link from my app, I just want to open the email app for the user. I don't want to call an Intent with the SENDTO action because the user will not be sending any mail

I just want to navigate user from my app to email app (received emails).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        onResult = { //Do something when user comes back in app }
    )

Button(onClick = {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL)
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
}
launcher.launch(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [makeMainSelectorActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#makeMainSelectorActivity(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) with the selector category [CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL). This returns an `ACTION_MAIN` intent which will attempt to launch the email app (it should show a selector if there are multiple email apps).